# Average waiting times in line

Tags: statistics

A local store has an average waiting time of 3 minutes.
I need to find the percentage of customers that wait less than 2 minutes and more than 4 minutes. 
The store is running a promotion where the customer's purchases are free if they wait longer than a certain time. If the store doesn't want to give away products to more than 3% of the customers. What should be advertised then?

Comment: What's the underlying distribution? Normal? Poisson?

Comment: A common model for waiting times is the exponential model. I expect that what you are supposed to use, but I am very uncomfortable about using it, particularly for tail probabilities.

Comment: That's the issue I haven't been given any more information than that.

Comment: @Grant: What class you are taking, and what chapter you are in, and what queueing systems you already understand are all important pieces of information that you that but which we don't. :-)   ETA: Upon closer reading, I guess there isn't any queueing; you just want the tail of a time distribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think it is not exponential distribution. Exp distribution is for waiting time between two events, not really the kind of waiting time in a store, more like the time the shopowner has to wait for the next customer to come

Comment: The exponential model is in fairly common use (particularly in introductory books) for service time. What would be almost decisive is if OP mentioned that the problem was in the exponential distribution section of the book!

Comment: This isn't from a textbook we got this handed out in our tutorial. We've been doing integral calculus and I'm really struggling to find the connection with what we've been doing. We've mostly been finding volumes and areas with integrals.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good bet that you are supposed to use an exponential distribution with mean 3 (rate 1/3) for the waiting time $X.$ Then it is an easy integration problem to find the answers to the first two questions, and not difficult to solve the final one. You can
find the pdf of this exponential distribution in a probability text or in the Wikipedia article on 'exponential distribution.' (An exponential distribution might be reasonably accurate unless
waiting lines for service are involved.)

Here are answers from R statistical software (in which the cdf is denoted `pexp`), against which you can
check your answers from calculus.

```
 pexp(2, rate=1/3)
 ## 0.4865829        # P(X < 2)
 1 - pexp(4, rate=1/3)
 ## 0.2635971        # P(X > 4)
 qexp(.97, rate=1/3)
 ## 10.51967         # P(X > 10.52) = 0.03
```

Here is a graph of the density function of $Exp(rate = 1/3)$ with vertical
dotted lines separating relevant areas.

[image]

Note: In case you are expected to use a uniform distribution, the
relevant choice would be $Unif(0, 6)$, and you can get probabilities
without calculus. But that would be an extremely unrealistic
distribution for waiting times.